# Can we get an identity of a delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Is it possible to generate an idenitity of a delegate to distinguish it from other delegate? Think of this code:

```
Func<int, int, int> delegate1 = a, b => a + b;
Func<int, int, int> delegate2 = a, b => a + b;
Func<int, int, int> delegate3 = a, b => a - b;
let id1 = id(delegate1);
let id2 = id(delegate2);
let id3 = id(delegate3);
Assert(id1 == id2);
Assert(id1 != id3);
```

The problem I want to solve is, I want to cache some JIT compiled GPU code in .NET. To make it easy to use, I want to let user send the delegate, and if the delegate is same, we try to find out the GPU code from a cache, rather than JIT compile it everytime:

```
Parallel(outputA, inputA1, inputA2, a, b => a + b); //should JIT compile GPU code, and cache it by its identity
Parallel(outputB, inputB1, inputB2, a, b => a + b); //should NOT JIT compile GPU code, and use the cached GPU code by its identity
```

One possible solution is to compare the expression string, but it still has problem to catch the clouser, such as:

```
int c = 0;
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> delegate1 = (a, b) => a + b + c;
c += 1;
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> delegate2 = (a, b) => a + b + c;
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> delegate3 = (a, b) => a - b - c;
Console.WriteLine(delegate1);
Console.WriteLine(delegate2);
Console.WriteLine(delegate1.ToString() == delegate2.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

As pointed out thanks to @SWeko and @Luaan, in the above example, `delegate1` and `delegate2` are actually the same. But the purpose of caching the delegate is in the following usage:

```
int c = 1;
Parallel(outputA, inputA1, inputA2, (a,b) => a+b); //do JIT compile of GPU code
c += 1;
Parallel(outputB, inputB1, inputB2, (a,b) => a+b); //as the delegate is same then the previouse one, it will not do JIT GPU code compiling, but then, that is wrong!
```

Comment: Maybe you can use [Expression trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) instead of `Func`. I'm not sure that they implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` as requested but you're able iterate through the structure and you can create your own HashCode - but it's not as simple as it sounds. - And I'm not sure that this will result in a performance benefit.

Comment: @Verarind then we can create expression tree from a delegate, but then again the question, can we simply compare the equaliaty of two expression tree objects?

Comment: Your delegates *aren't* the same. Inspect `delegate1.Method`. Inspect `delegate2.Method`. They're two different functions that happen to do the same thing. You ask about the identity of a delegate, but your code already properly detects that. What you're really interested in is something else.

Comment: @XiangZhang as I said before: Not sure. Maybe `Equals` is implemented to handle different instances having the same content but I guess it's not. In That case you've to implement it by your own.

Comment: Actually, in the second example, both delegates will use the updated value of `c`.

Comment: Oh, but the closure you make *is* the same - if you actually try to execute both `delegate1` and `delegate2`, you'll get the exact same result. That's how closures work.

Comment: @SWeko  , thanks for your pointing out that, I actually again updated the question, which describes why it doesn't meet my requirement. Actually no I think this is not possible, I have to do some extra compilation during compile time to solve this.

Comment: @Luaan thanks for your pointing out that, I actually again updated the question, which describes why it doesn't meet my requirement. Actually no I think this is not possible, I have to do some extra compilation during compile time to solve this.

Comment: @XiangZhang Well, that's pretty simple, really. Either your JITted code is parametrizable (in which case, just treat all the closures as parameters and reuse the same expression trees), or it isn't (in which case, make sure you compare all the closure constants).

Answer (score 4):

One (relatively naive) approach would be to use `Expression<Func>`s instead of `Func`'s themselves, as they have much more detailed info, that allows you to analyze stuff. E.g.

```
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> delegate1 = (a, b) => a + b;
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> delegate2 = (a, b) => a + b;
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> delegate3 = (a, b) => a - b;
var id1 = id(delegate1);
var id2 = id(delegate2);
var id3 = id(delegate3);
Debug.Assert(id1 == id2);
Debug.Assert(id1 != id3);
```

where `id` is as trivial as:

```
public static string id(Expression<Func<int, int, int>> expression)
{
    return expression.ToString();
}
```

passes the tests.

---

Note that this is not a complete solution, and has lots and lots of issues. If you need a comprehensive comparison, you'd need to take into account the full nature of the expression, including (but not limited too) types going in and out of the expression, methods calls, closure access, etc, etc..
I don't think this is solvable at all in the general case, but usually it can be restricted to some more specialized case, that can be solved.

Comment: Good idea - but a type conversion will be represented in string as `Convert(x)` regardless of the type to which it will be converted. But maybe in this special case it will be enough.

Comment: ah, good idea, but compare two strings might leads to performance issue.

Comment: and if there is clouser of some variable, then it might fail. See the updated question , where I code an excpetion of this test. Uhmm, then it looks hard.

Comment: You could make a .startswith with ordinal search  that should at least lessen the performance loss for the string comparison (worked wonders for me for a string check performance problem)

Comment: @XiangZhang You've performance issues at comparing string? Maybe you should redesign your code. [Don't use lambda](http://byterot.blogspot.de/2012/05/performance-comparison-of-code.html) because they're too slow. After that you can use [NGen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.110).aspx) to precompile your code.

Comment: @Verarind , well, the string comparsion solution actually have a problem of catching the clouser, see the updated question. So I think the solution might be do some extra compilation at compile time, not do JIT compiling during runtime.

Comment: @XiangZhang Yes I see the point of clouser. My comment refers to your comment about the performance issue. The clouser is a problem.

Comment: Not to mention that string comparison would treat `a+b` as different from `b+a`. I intend this answer as just a trivial solution to a very untrivial problem.

Comment: @SWeko: just be careful with this way of ID'ing the expressions. `Func[int,int] "x => 2*x"` will be detected as different from ``Func[int,int] "z => 2*z"`` and more importantly `Func[double,double] "x => 2*x"` will be detected as a match. If you use only one type of a delegate, it's ok. But if you intend on widening the types, such ID function **must at least** additionally add information about all parameter types and to be 100% safe, and also the type of closure involved... and in some cases, you may even need information about involved assemblies..

Comment: @SWeko: about the assemblies - it's not obvious at first, but think of having two libraries, both define type named "X", both contain the same-looking expression `param => X.Foo(param)`, but their Foo is implemented differently (i.e. dll1 is in version 3, and dll2 is in version 1). You actually can run into case where such two assemblies produce similar-looking expressions and your module could be trying to process them. It's a complex problem, very unlikely to happen, but it's worth being aware of. Sometimes SimpleCodeText+AllParamTypes(even with namespaces/assemblies) is not enough.

Comment: An even more confusing situation, the `X` is the same, but `Foo` is two differently implemented extension methods? Yes, to get this thing absolutely correct is a hard problem. (added a "disclaimer" to the end of the answer)

Answer (score 3):

You need to work at the `Expression` level here. The C# compiler does not guarantee that identical lambdas end up with the same delegate object. This optimization is not being performed right now but there is a GitHub issue. Even if it is performed it will work one assembly at a time which might not be enough for you. If the delegate captures closure values then this will not ever work.

I once did this in order to cache LINQ 2 SQL compiled queries automatically given a query. It is not trivial to compare expression trees. `ToString` is not full fidelity and it is slow. You will need to write your own comparer class. I think there's code for that on the web as a starting point.

As an example, when you compare constant expressions you can't just do `ReferenceEquals(val1, val2)`. You have to actually special case many types such as boxed primitive types. They can have the same value but boxed with different object identities.

You also will need to write a hash code function because you probably want to lookup cache results using a hash table.

You also will get GC problems because expression trees can hold onto arbitrary objects. Basically, a closure can randomly hold onto local variables in unexpected ways. So what I did was to sanitize trees before caching them. I deleted all constants from them that were not safe.

> Is it possible to generate an identity of a delegate to distinguish it from other delegate?

Yes, but it involves manually comparing and hashing the expression tree.

Answer (score 2):

An option here is to use `Dictionary<T1, T2>` to hold string ID and our delegates (string Key contains sorted expression concatenated with value from some test invocation [this generates an UID of some sort]) and value is our Func delegate. The expression compiles only first time when we map our expression converted to string to ID in `_delegatesMapping` :

```
public class Funker
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _delegatesMapping;
    private static Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int>> _delegates;
    public static Funker Instance { get; private set; }

    static Funker()
    {
        _delegatesMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        _delegates = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int>>();
        Instance = new Funker();
    }

    private Funker() { }

    public Func<int, int, int> this[Expression<Func<int, int, int>> del]
    {
        get
        {
            string expStr = del.ToString();

            var parameters = del.Parameters;

            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
                expStr = expStr.Replace(parameters[i].Name, String.Concat('_' + i));

            Func<int, int, int> _Del = null;

            if (!_delegatesMapping.ContainsKey(expStr))
            {
                _Del = del.Compile();
                _delegatesMapping.Add(expStr, new String(expStr.OrderBy(ch => ch).ToArray()) + "|" + _Del(55, 77));
            }

            if (!_delegates.ContainsKey(_delegatesMapping[expStr])) _delegates.Add(_delegatesMapping[expStr], _Del ?? del.Compile());
            return _delegates[_delegatesMapping[expStr]];
        }
    }
}
```

We need this `_delegatesMapping` to store our UID records in format Expression string -> UID. It also allows us to perform quick (almost `n(1)`) lookup rather then calculating UID every time when we need it.

So the whole operation looks like :

*Expression -> textExp -> new record in _delegatesMapping (textExp -> UID)
new record in `_delegates[UID]`*

And when accessing it's all the way back. First we get UID than delegate:

*Expression --> textExp -->  _delegates[_delegatesMapping[textExp]] (returns delegate if it exists in dictionary).*

**Example of usage** :

```
class Program
{        

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var funker = Funker.Instance;

        var del1 = funker[(a, b) => a + 71 + 12 + b];
        var del2 = funker[(hello, world) => 71 + hello + world + 12];
        var del3 = funker[(a, c) => a + 17 + 21 + c];

        Debug.Assert(del1 == del2);
        Debug.Assert(del1 == del3);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

P.S.
But as SWeko already wrote in his answer :

> Note that this is not a complete solution, and has lots and lots of
>   issues. If you need a comprehensive comparison, you'd need to take
>   into account the full nature of the expression, including (but not
>   limited too) types going in and out of the expression, methods calls,
>   closure access, etc, etc..

Comment: What is `expStr.OrderBy(ch => ch).ToArray()`?

Comment: @usr well this line 'resets' the order for expression, eg `(a, b) => (((a + 7) + 5) + b)` and  `(b, a) => (((7 + b) + 5) + a)` (same exp with different order) will both be converted to identical expression (id) something like `(((())))+++,ab57=>`

Comment: @usr you're right, updated my answer to cover this scenario